# Graph of an operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm currently looking at the following problem from Simon and Reid's methods of mathematical physics book 1, functional analysis. In particular, exercise VIII.1: -

Let $\{ \varphi_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, and let $e_{\infty}$ be a vector in $\mathscr{H}$ that is not a finite linear combination of the $\varphi_n$. Let $D$ be the set of finite linear combinations of $\varphi_n$ and $e_{\infty}$, and on $D$, define $$T \left( be_{\infty} + \sum_{i=1}^N c_i \varphi_i \right) = be_{\infty}.$$ Show that $\overline{\Gamma(T)}$ contains both $\langle e_{\infty}, e_{\infty} \rangle$ and $\langle e_{\infty}, 0 \rangle$ and thus is not the graph of a linear operator.

I've been able to show what was required, I'm confused however by why the fact that $\langle e_{\infty}, e_{\infty} \rangle$ and $\langle e_{\infty}, 0 \rangle$ being contained in the closure of $\Gamma(T)$ shows that $\Gamma(T)$ is not the graph of a linear operator.

Comment: Are there any topological requirements on a linear operator assumed? An operator is closable when the closure of its graph is the graph of a linear operator. Of course the closure cannot be the graph of any (single-valued) function since it wouldn't be well-defined. Maybe they assume that an operator is at least closable?

Answer (score 0):

"$\overline{\Gamma(T)}$ is the graph of an operator $U$" means $\Gamma(U) = \overline{\Gamma(T)}$. By definition $\Gamma(U)$ contains pairs $\langle e_{\infty}, Ue_{\infty} \rangle$ and (since linear operators are single-valued) there is only one pair with $e_{\infty}$ on the left.